# Java equivalent of .NET's Version class?

Tags: java, .net, system.version

Is there a Java equivalent of .NET's System.Version class? How do I say this in Java?

```
Version myVersion = new Version(2, 1);
```

Comment: What properties of the version object do you need? Just a major / minor / revision / build tuple, or the conversion to / from binary, or the comparators, or something else?

Comment: Really just the major/minor tuple and comparators. I guess I could implement it myself, but was hoping for a readymade class.

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised there isn't one in Apache Commons or Google Guava (at least as far as I can see).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a class from OSGi:
  http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Version.html

And the corresponding source:
  http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/osgi/framework/Version.java.html

Answer (score 1):

To get a system/modules version e.g. String.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()

If you want to specify your own version, create a Manifest.txt file to be added to your jar-file as in this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html)

See also the javadoc for [Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html)

Comment: But I am afraid it is just a string in the end.

Comment: I ended up implementing my own Version tuple, but thanks for the links, I've been using them!